# xcode creates breakpoint for no reason

Tags: swift, xcode, breakpoints

Im doing a bit of practice coding in Swift, trying to work it all out and learn as I go, I know how to stop the breakpoint from occurring but im wondering why it happens all the time and if its possible to stop it permanently.

if the activate breakpoints button is turned on (and it seems to turn its self on all the time), xcode won't load the app in simulator and instead breaks at this line

```
let snakeHead = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "snakehead1.png")
```

now as far as I can tell there isn't anything wrong with the code, it sits within a function that does a few other things but other than that its pretty straight forward. As mentioned i can stop the breakpoint from occurring by deselecting the button but I'm just wondering why it keeps happening, is it something I've unintentionally done?

edit: screenshot added

[image]

Comment: Could you show a screen shot of your Breakpoints Inspector? This will show what breakpoints you have.

Comment: If you hit the continue button, in the debugger, after it stops, does it then continue to execute OK?  (If it does not, does it eventually produce an error?  Does it remain stopped?)

Comment: Yes, I agree with @matt a screenshot would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all probability, we break at this line when breakpoints are activated because you have in fact set a breakpoint at this line.

If you don't want that to happen, delete or disable the breakpoint that is set at this line.

Comment: How do you create breakpoints though? I've never done it intentionally

Comment: Just accidentally clicking in the "gutter" to the left of the code would do it.

Comment: Your screen shot shows that you have 11 breakpoints. That didn't happen all by itself! _You created them._ And that's 11 places in your code where you will pause if breakpoints are enabled and activated. _That is what a breakpoint is. It is a point in your code where we break._

Comment: oh ok, had no idea thats what they were. Thanks heaps!